# My method does not work inside of onKeyEntered

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation, geofire

I am trying to create an app that will allow users to rent a car nearest to them. I want to build a cardView with a textView and imageView once i find the nearest car, I created the method buildCardView to do that. My problem is that the cardView is not getting created when its called. buildCardView works fine when I call it directly, but not when called inside of the Geoquery onKeyEntered method. I debugged the code and the method buildCardView is getting called inside of on onKeyEntered but the cardView is not visible. Below is the code for that calls the firebase method.

```
FindCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                   findClosestCars();
        }
    });
```

Below is the firebase method that calls buildCardView

```
private void findClosestCars() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RentersMenuPageActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

     //  turnOnLocationUpdates();
        //fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("Lenders");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseReference);
        GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), radius);
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();

        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
           //
                //  Toast.makeText(RentersMenuPageActivity.this, "You Found a Lender",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                  //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                //showPictureAndPrice();

                if (!driverFound) {
                    driverFound = true;
                    driverFoundID = key;

                    closestLender = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("Lenders").child(driverFoundID);

                    String [] lenderLocations;

                    buildCardView();
                }

               radius++;
            }
```

Below is buildCardView that inflates a smaller view inside the main one (works when called directly but not from onkeyentered)

```
private void buildCardView(){
    Toast.makeText(RentersMenuPageActivity.this, "You Found a Lender",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card,null);

   // CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    Button rentCarButton = view.findViewById(R.id.rentCarButton);
    TextView price= view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView makeandmodel = view.findViewById(R.id.makeandmodel);
    ImageView imageView =view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewScroll);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what isn't working. Instead of explaining in words, I recommend locally debugging and telling us the result of that. So if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo when I debug the app everything inside of the buildCarView method is getting populated but I cant see the cardView, textView and imageView.

Comment: So it's an issue related more to views rather than Firebase, right?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen does the question make more sense now?

Comment: @AlexMamo I am not sure.The cardview works fine when I call it directly from the Find car button. The card view is only not visible when I call it inside of the on Key entered method.

Answer (score 0):

try creating activity instance as

```
AppCompatActivity activity = YourActivity.this;
```

Then use your code as:

```
private void buildCardView(){
    Toast.makeText(activity, "You Found a Lender",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //changed here
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    //changed here
    View view =activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card,null); 

    // CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    Button rentCarButton = view.findViewById(R.id.rentCarButton);
    TextView price= view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView makeandmodel = view.findViewById(R.id.makeandmodel);
    ImageView imageView =view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewScroll);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutMainLayout.addView(view);
}
```

Tested on GeoQueryDataEventListener and the card view came up.